# Getting error of loading scss when upgraded Angular 6 application to Angular 8

Tags: angular, updates, angular8

I am updating Angular 6 application to Angular 8. After updating several packages and fixing many errors, I'm finally stuck with this error

I have tried the following steps so far:

1. Uninstall webpack.
2. Remove node_modules.
3. Install webpack gloabally
4. Run `npm i`

I'm receiving the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css'
  in [
    c:\xampp\htdocs\hrflo\admin_frontend_updated\src\assets\scss
  ]
    at resolveModule.catch.catch (c:\xampp\htdocs\hrflo\admin_frontend_updated\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13)
```

My 'package.json' file is:

```
{
  "name": "hrflo-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.0.7",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.0.2",
    "angular-calendar": "0.27.18",
    "angular-datatables": "^8.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "chartist": "0.11.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.5.3",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.5.3",
    "datatables.net-colreorder": "^1.5.1",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-dt": "^1.5.1",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-editor": "^1.6.5",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-responsive-dt": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-select": "^1.3.0",
    "datatables.net-select-dt": "^1.3.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.1",
    "daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-chartist": "4.1.0",
    "ng2-charts": "2.3.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.5.0",
    "ng4-intl-phone": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "7.3.0",
    "ngx-scrollbar": "^5.0.2",
    "ngx-select-ex": "^3.5.9",
    "ngx-toastr": "10.2.0",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "print-js": "^1.0.61",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.5",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.13",
    "@types/datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.0",
    "@types/datatables.net-select": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.22",
    "@types/node": "~12.7.4",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.19.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
}
```

My 'angular.json' file is:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "hrflo-admin": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/hrflo-admin",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css",
              "./src/assets/scss/style.scss",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-select-dt/css/select.dataTables.min.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder-dt/css/colReorder.dataTables.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-dt/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css",
              "src/assets/dist/css/editor.dataTables.min.css",
              "src/assets/dist/css/editor.bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/assets/dist/css/chosen.css",
              "src/assets/scss/print-js/print.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/pace-js/pace.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
              "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-select/js/dataTables.select.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/dataTables.editor.min.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/chosen.jquery.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/editor.chosen.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/editor.ckeditor.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/editor.Mchosen.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/rangedate.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/scan.js",
              "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
              "node_modules/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js",
              "src/assets/js/wizard/jquery.steps.js",
              "src/assets/js/wizard/main.js",
              "src/assets/js/wizard/theme-map.js",
              "src/assets/js/print-js/print.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hrflo-admin:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "hrflo-admin:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hrflo-admin:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "hrflo-admin-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "hrflo-admin:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "hrflo-admin:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "hrflo-admin"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no longer a /release/-folder in the url ,since version 16.0.0

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1743#issuecomment-528952503

so, you should change your import-url: "@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.css"

Comment: @Shan did my answer helped you?